# How To Make an Object Keep on It's Position When Play Button Clicked

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new with unity, this is my first project. I want to make a racing game, as we know unity has that kind of game on it's standard assets package.

Now, my problem is I try to improve that standard packages by combining my own ground design and unity's standard assets car script. 
First Position:

[image]

I've done with rebuild and combining those elements, then when I play the game then the car's position changes. I don't have any idea about what happens. This is the result :

[image]

Can somebody here help find out the solution? Thank you

Comment: Maybe it isn't changing, have you checked your camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the images you show it seems like the car sinks a little bit in the ground. This can happens because the car has got a rigidbody and when you press play it is affected by the gravity of the scene, so it falls until meeting another collider, in this case the one of the ground (If the ground doesn't fall as well is because it hasn't got a rigidbody or is static).

What you should do is to mark the collider of the ground as  [static](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) (in case it wasn't static already) and then reshape it, so its size matches with the shape of the ground. The other option is that the car has got a collider just covering to the point of the wheels until it sinks.

Check the shape of both colliders (car and ground) and ensure they cover entirely each game object.